# The Widgets keeps working weirdly even though I use the null-safety package called: Liquid_Swipe

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using liquid-swipe package to make my widgets swipes. But it only shows some widget eventhough I type all the Widgets name in the page controller.

here is my code:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'app_localizations.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String locale = 'vn';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pages = [
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleHoTay",
          "https://scontent.fdad1-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/183693736_3624218511137458_7956329269635962748_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=0kT31rhRFGEAX9BrNch&_nc_ht=scontent.fdad1-3.fna&oh=7c20ff55324c19294ebaba818bb1330f&oe=61464632",
          "/1",
          300,
          200 - 113,
          100),
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleDapW",
          "https://scontent.fdad2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/p180x540/65041942_480246145879985_4632209584075833344_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=mwdEX0vNXzcAX-dN-rH&tn=oayM1mpnEQGRTiAo&_nc_ht=scontent.fdad2-1.fna&oh=33132f742d96c2da2e50076cd0ba3a75&oe=6146F4C1",
          "/2",
          300,
          200 - 106,
          128),
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleNhaNgucDm",
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRbzUe3DfwcFEuvZ1hcADo0Pyd2MLzV53Lssw&usqp=CAU",
          "/3",
          350,
          200 - 74 - 30 - 81,
          124),
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleNuiLua",
          "https://scontent.fdad1-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/s600x600/57908950_591353494702644_7718385079377985536_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=gVM4bC4hCSMAX9kUFEf&_nc_ht=scontent.fdad1-3.fna&oh=bc97d4baf985e69dd1a398fc8ea037b1&oe=614E3A97",
          "/4",
          450,
          200 - 74 - 30,
          218),
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleDoi",
          "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YoMlSaIM9Y0/YKfDdyuDIHI/AAAAAAAALco/dCqRdY-XfK8hfrJf7aFKYrU41GDE4tzVQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/1.jpg",
          "/5",
          380,
          200,
          298),
      placeButton(
          context,
          "titleVuonXoai",
          "https://scontent.fdad1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/79464050_2175103252589973_7580698426552090624_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Q_WhMjmMcmcAX983e-B&_nc_ht=scontent.fdad1-2.fna&oh=955405f9204ee27083bb520a65f24f89&oe=614B45B9",
          "/7",
          450,
          200 - 18 - 52 - 30 - 16 - 30,
          156)
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue.shade100,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                child: Image.network(
                    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnfPY__kY3d7pRl5vyADEFdVLcOp6gUZ4Z1w&usqp=CAU",
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    height: 200,
                    width: double.infinity),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 115, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Dak Mil",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "MoonShine",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 150, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                  "A great place that helps you enjoy the nature and escape from reality",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Swistblnk",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 21)),
            ),
          ]),
          Expanded(
            child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => LiquidSwipe(
                    pages: pages,
                    enableSideReveal: true,
                    waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget placeButton(BuildContext context, String name, String url, String id,
    double height, double width, int likeCount) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 50, right: 50),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, id),
            child: Image.network(url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, id),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.lightBlue.shade100,
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 270),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 230),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(name),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "iCiel", fontSize: 30)),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: width),
            LikeButton(
              onTap: onLikeButtonTapped,
              likeCount: likeCount,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async {
  /// send your request here
  // final bool success= await sendRequest();

  /// if failed, you can do nothing
  // return success? !isLiked:isLiked;

  return !isLiked;
}
```

don't mind to ask me about the project, just help me as soon as possible.
P/s: The is another error that appears in some image in my app: type null is not a subtype of type list int in type cast. It could be the reason to the problem. If you know how to fix this, please tell me too.

Comment: Maybe you should fix the error in the PS first. If your program has errors, it is normal that the UI does not behave as you expect it to. Post the error, post the line it appears in.

Comment: It appears in every network image's url that I get, and I can't understand why it works in my old laptop. I just copy all the code from my old to my new laptop. And my old images works just fine . Both of my laptop has that same error above.